# Spring Boot Security - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot pass a null GrantedAuthority collection

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I am new to Spring boot and Spring Security. Is there any issues with my current Spring boot version 1.3.7.RELEASE? How can I fixed this problem?

My `SecurityConfig.java` looks like as the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    public void configureAuth(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("thomas")
                .password("password")
            .and()
                .withUser("joe")
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER");
    }
}
```

This is my `pom.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>springsecuritydemo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>springsecuritydemo</name>
<description>springsecuritydemo</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Log file:

```
2016-07-31 20:08:33.480  INFO 2130 --- [           main]     c.example.SpringsecuritydemoApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-07-31 20:08:33.589  INFO 2130 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6b0c2d26: startup date [Sun Jul 31 20:08:33 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-07-31 20:08:35.504  INFO 2130 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$285af57d] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-07-31 20:08:35.542  INFO 2130 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'objectPostProcessor' of type [class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-07-31 20:08:35.546  INFO 2130 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler@5669c5fb' of type [class org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-07-31 20:08:35.564  INFO 2130 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4d2f982f] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-07-31 20:08:35.595  INFO 2130 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' of type [class org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-07-31 20:08:36.237  INFO 2130 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-07-31 20:08:36.264  INFO 2130 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-07-31 20:08:36.267  INFO 2130 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.36
2016-07-31 20:08:36.469  INFO 2130 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-07-31 20:08:36.470  INFO 2130 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2899 ms
2016-07-31 20:08:37.033  INFO 2130 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-07-31 20:08:37.034  INFO 2130 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-07-31 20:08:37.034  INFO 2130 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2016-07-31 20:08:37.034  INFO 2130 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2016-07-31 20:08:37.036  INFO 2130 --- [ost-startStop-1] .e.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2016-07-31 20:08:37.036  INFO 2130 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-07-31 20:08:37.497 ERROR 2130 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot pass a null GrantedAuthority collection
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1060) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:326) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:235) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:199) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:109) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4689) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5329) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_25]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot pass a null GrantedAuthority collection
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot pass a null GrantedAuthority collection
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115) ~[spring-core-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.sortAuthorities(User.java:150) ~[spring-security-core-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.<init>(User.java:110) ~[spring-security-core-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.provisioning.UserDetailsManagerConfigurer$UserDetailsBuilder.build(UserDetailsManagerConfigurer.java:263) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.provisioning.UserDetailsManagerConfigurer$UserDetailsBuilder.access$000(UserDetailsManagerConfigurer.java:84) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.provisioning.UserDetailsManagerConfigurer.initUserDetailsService(UserDetailsManagerConfigurer.java:61) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.userdetails.UserDetailsServiceConfigurer.configure(UserDetailsServiceConfigurer.java:48) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.userdetails.UserDetailsServiceConfigurer.configure(UserDetailsServiceConfigurer.java:35) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.configure(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:383) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:329) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration.java:81) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.authenticationManager(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:237) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:175) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:290) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:67) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at com.example.config.SecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$838a4505.init(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:370) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:324) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:105) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$36de5a36.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$3(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$36de5a36$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5961a67e.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$36de5a36.springSecurityFilterChain(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted

2016-07-31 20:08:37.499 ERROR 2130 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
2016-07-31 20:08:37.501 ERROR 2130 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
2016-07-31 20:08:37.542  WARN 2130 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodSecurityInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor]: Factory method 'methodSecurityInterceptor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration$EnableGlobalAuthenticationAutowiredConfigurer@1ff6fe76 to already built object
2016-07-31 20:08:37.548  INFO 2130 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2016-07-31 20:08:37.553 ERROR 2130 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodSecurityInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor]: Factory method 'methodSecurityInterceptor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration$EnableGlobalAuthenticationAutowiredConfigurer@1ff6fe76 to already built object
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar:1.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:760) [spring-boot-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar:1.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar:1.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306) [spring-boot-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar:1.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar:1.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar:1.3.7.RELEASE]
    at com.example.SpringsecuritydemoApplication.main(SpringsecuritydemoApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor]: Factory method 'methodSecurityInterceptor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration$EnableGlobalAuthenticationAutowiredConfigurer@1ff6fe76 to already built object
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration$EnableGlobalAuthenticationAutowiredConfigurer@1ff6fe76 to already built object
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.add(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:195) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.apply(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:146) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration.java:78) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.authenticationManager(GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.java:257) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.methodSecurityInterceptor(GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.java:123) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4d2f982f.CGLIB$methodSecurityInterceptor$2(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4d2f982f$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$601d8069.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4d2f982f.methodSecurityInterceptor(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted

2016-07-31 20:08:37.562  WARN 2130 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Error handling failed (Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'metaDataSourceAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' is defined)
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot pass a null
>   GrantedAuthority collection

The error is obvious, you should assign at least one role to your first user. For example, you can assign him a `USER` role too:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    public void configureAuth(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("thomas")
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER")
            .and()
                .withUser("joe")
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to return custom error message on this exception.