# Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

As I'm new to Spring and Spring Security and following some YouTube tutorial I coded exactly same and getting above error.

**Error**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot pass a null GrantedAuthority collection
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:625) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1126) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:307) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:848) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:865) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:548) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:797) [spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:421) [spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:340) [spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) [spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1279) [spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at com.spring.security.SpringsecurityApplication.main(SpringsecurityApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot pass a null GrantedAuthority collection
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot pass a null GrantedAuthority collection
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198) ~[spring-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.sortAuthorities(User.java:163) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.<init>(User.java:123) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User$UserBuilder.build(User.java:535) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.provisioning.UserDetailsManagerConfigurer$UserDetailsBuilder.build(UserDetailsManagerConfigurer.java:279) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.provisioning.UserDetailsManagerConfigurer.initUserDetailsService(UserDetailsManagerConfigurer.java:60) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.userdetails.UserDetailsServiceConfigurer.configure(UserDetailsServiceConfigurer.java:47) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.userdetails.UserDetailsServiceConfigurer.configure(UserDetailsServiceConfigurer.java:34) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.configure(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:384) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:330) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:201) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:321) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:92) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at com.spring.security.config.SecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1d8d4c86.init(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:371) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:325) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:104) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$efe529b0.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$1(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$efe529b0$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8d960911.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
```

**Security Config File**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
    .withUser("abhi").password("test").and()
    .withUser("kumar").password("test2");
}
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
    .anyRequest()
    .fullyAuthenticated()
    .and().httpBasic();
    httpSecurity.csrf().disable();

}}
```

I referred to similar questions also but none solve my error. This is my first program using Spring Security.

Comment: Based on the error that you're getting looks like you need to assign a role to the users defined. Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38687209/spring-boot-security-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-cannot-pass-a-null-gr#38687335

Comment: thanks @madhu but why roles? can you plz explain it

Comment: I've explained it in my answer. Does that clear your doubt and answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to allow for all user roles, use below but roles has to pass as blank.
Change it and you should be good.

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("abhi").password("test").roles("")
                 .and()
                .withUser("kumar").password("test2").roles("");
    }
```

Comment: thanks @kj007 but why roles because every User can't be admin or normal user i hope u understand what i'm trying to say? can you plz explain it

Comment: Grand Authority can not be null only, it can pass empty if there no user role as when it compare then null throws error so in your case pass empty as I advised in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

When you override the `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` method by using `auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser`, you are essentially creating a new User (of type `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User`).

Whenever a new User object needs to be created and added to the spring security ecosystem, it needs 3 Non-nullable arguments. They are

- `String username`
- `String password`
- `Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities`

So when you provide username and password using `withUser(String username)` and `password(String password)`, you must also provide the authority to the user by using either `roles(String... roles)`,`authorities(GrantedAuthority... authorities)`,`authorities(List<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities)` or `authorities(String... authorities)`. The easiest for you would be to use the `roles(String... roles)` method and provide the role that you want, like `role("USER")` or in case you don't want to provide any role, just use `role("")` and that would pass an empty collection to the `Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities` attribute of the User object. So essentially, you need to modify the `configure` method as below :

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
     .withUser("abhi").password("test").roles("") //or .roles("USER")
     .and()
     .withUser("kumar").password("test2").roles(""); //or .roles("USER")
}
```

The below is from the documentation of `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User`

> @throws IllegalArgumentException if a `null` value was passed either as
>        a parameter or as an element in the `GrantedAuthority` collection

Comment: Can you pls guide here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68482157/caused-by-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-pattern-cannot-be-null-or-empty ?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid `Cannot pass a null GrantedAuthority collection` you must assign user roles to each user as `.roles("USER")`.

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
    .withUser("abhi").password("test").roles("USER")
    .and()
    .withUser("kumar").password("test2").roles("USER");
}
```

Comment: thanks @benjamin but why roles? can you plz explain it.

Answer (score -3):

remove from class "extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter" and @override and program will compile :)

Comment: I am learning spring boot and finding things in tutorials which are deprecated it would be cool if anyone could suggest any resource to stay updated with spring security